# ActionController::UnknownFormat: when using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actioncontroller

I am creating a simple API to perform CRUD actions on contacts. `:index`, `:show`, `:create` and `:update` methods are working properly and they all pass their respective request rspec tests. The problem only arise in the `:destroy` method. The `:destroy` action looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    @contact.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render action: :index }
    end
  end
end
```

The spec to test `DELETE` request looks like this:

```
 describe "DELETE /api/v1/contacts/:id" do
  before(:each) do
   @contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact)
  end

  it "it should have a status code of 200" do
    delete "/api/v1/contacts/#{@contact.id}"
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end

  it "It should delete a contact" do
    expect{
      delete "/api/v1/contacts/#{@contact.id}"
    }.to change(Contact, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

when i run the test i get this error message:

```
Failure/Error: delete "/api/v1/contacts/#{@contact.id}"
 ActionController::UnknownFormat:
   ActionController::UnknownFormat
# ./app/controllers/api/v1/contacts_controller.rb:67:in `destroy'
```

`respond_to do |format|` is line 67 in `contacts_controller.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the format of your request to JSON, i.e. replace

```
delete "/api/v1/contacts/#{@contact.id}"
```

by

```
delete "/api/v1/contacts/#{@contact.id}.json"
```

that would allow the `format` logic to figure out that you want the reply rendered in JSON which it knows about.